# Reading an incoming/received Lora frame with I-Cube End-node sample code

Tags: stm32, packet, packet-capture, lorawan

I'm using the [ST I-Cube End-node sample code](https://my.st.com/content/my_st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcu-mpu-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32cube-expansion-packages/i-cube-lrwan.html) (in C) embedded on the [B-L072Z-LRWAN1](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/b-l072z-lrwan1.html) discovery kit board and transmitting a LoRaWAN packet to my End-node device.
I'm seeing that the packet has been received by the end device because it prints:

> "PACKET RECEIVED ON PORT 1"

But I don't know how or where the received packet is stored.

How can I print and access the packet data/payload that I have transmitted to my node?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function with the signature `void LORA_RxData(lora_AppData_t *AppData)` has been declared and defined wherein the `lora_AppData_t` contains the downlink LoRaWAN payload.

The available member variables are:
message buffer: `AppData->Buff`
Size of the message buffer: `AppData->BuffSize`
Port of the received message: `AppData->Port`

This all can be found in the files `lora.h` and `lora.c`. These files contain ST's implemenentation of the [LoRaMac-node](https://github.com/Lora-net/LoRaMac-node)

The function is defined with `__weak` so you can define your own `LORA_RxData` to process the data on your own terms. If you don't redefine it it will use the default.

Comment: Perfect!
Works!